Incorrect value of CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR when using cibuildwheel and scikit-build-core on GitHub macos-14 runner
Below are demo files to reproduce the issue. I expect the value of CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR should be arm64. However, it is x86_64. See line 1233 in the Build wheels section, which corresponds to the command message("CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}") in the CMakeLists.txt file
main.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello\n";
}

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(hello)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
message("CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
add_executable(hello main.cpp)

build-wheel.yml
name: build-wheels

on:
  push:

jobs:
  build_wheels:
    name: Build wheel
    runs-on: macos-14

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Select Xcode
        run: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_15.4.app
      
      - name: Install Homebrew and packages
        run: |
          /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
          brew update
          brew install ninja

      - name: Build wheels
        uses: pypa/cibuildwheel@v2.19
        env:
          CIBW_BUILD: cp38-macosx_arm64
          CIBW_BUILD_VERBOSITY: 2
          CIBW_ENVIRONMENT_MACOS: >
            CC=gcc-14
            CXX=g++-14
            MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=13.0

pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["scikit-build-core>=0.9.0"]
build-backend = "scikit_build_core.build"

[project]
name = "hello"
version = "0.0.1dev0"

requires-python = ">=3.8"
dependencies = []

classifiers = [
  "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 or later (GPLv3+)",
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only",
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11",
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.12",
]


[tool.scikit-build]
wheel.expand-macos-universal-tags = true
cmake.version = ">=3.25"
cmake.build-type = "Release"
cmake.verbose = true
logging.level = "INFO"

[tool.cibuildwheel]
build = "*"
skip = "cp3{6,7}-*"

If I directly build the program using the workflow file below. I got the correct value of CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR, which is arm64. See line 29 in the Build section.
build.yml
name: build

on:
  push:

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: macos-14

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Select Xcode
        run: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_15.4.app
      
      - name: Install Homebrew and packages
        run: |
          /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
          brew update
          brew install ninja

      - name: "Build"
        run: |
          rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build
          cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-14 \
                -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-14 \
                -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
                -GNinja .. 
          ninja


please show a [mre]

Looks like absl is configured differently in those approaches. You need to reduce the problem to one, for which you could be able to post the code directly in your question post.

@AlanBirtles Please check the example above

@Tsyvarev I believe I found the issue. the value of CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR is not correct. I rephased my question. see the example above. but I don't know the origin of the issue and how to fix it.

I'd guess you're launching cmake from an intel process, you can either just override the value of CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR or use the arch command when launching cmake to force it to run as arm

@AlanBirtles resolved. see my answer below.

Not sure why your answer was deleted but presumably its because it was mostly just a link, answers should be self contained, links can be added for context but the answer should remain useful if (or more likely when) the link breaks in the future.
